# Export contracts to two or more folders

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I´m trying to automate as much as I could my truffle process and I wanna export the contracts during the "truffle migrate" command to two separate folders.

Imagine that I have a frontend and backend that use the smart contracts created by truffle.

I changed my truffle-config.js with "contracts_build_directory", but I want to export all contracts to two folders at the same time.

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own shell script to copy the file into the folder you want. Then pack it into a script along with truffle migrate.

<deploy.sh>

```sh
postMigration() {
    cp contract.json path/to/another/folder/contract.json
}

truffle migrate
postMigration
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering that I could do it with truffle.

Comment: Definitely yes, as truffle migration file is the javascript file, we can achieve the same result using the js. You can read it more [here](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations.html#migration-files)